Crack in exterior concrete block wall near large window
My 1949 built home has concrete block exterior walls. One wall has a 6x6' picture window, and near the corner is a crack. It appears to have been an issue for previous owners because there are signs of half assed repair (slapping plaster and paint over it, for example).
I'm looking for a way to repair this that will preclude future cracks. What's partly in there is some kind of old polymer or epoxy.
Ideas?


that looks serious

Can you excavate down to actual concrete?
